# Return byte[] from C# XML function

Tags: c#, function

This function converts XML to HTML with XSL. I need to save the HTML created in memory for use after

```
public void CreateHtml(string xmlRoute, string xlsRoute)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bote = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Cargamos la hoja de estilo que utilizaremos
        XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
        xslt.Load(xlsRoute);
        //Carga el archivo que deseamos transformar.
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xmlRoute);
        //Instanciamos XmlTextWriter con una consola de salida.
        XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
        xslt.Transform(doc, null, writer, null);
        writer.Close();
        //Declarar y crear un nuevo objeto XslCompiledTransform
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        //Cargamos el Xls que utilizaremos
        transform.Load(xlsRoute);
        //Generamos nuestro Html
        transform.Transform(xmlRoute, "Prueba002.pdf");
    }
```

The purpose is to change type of function to byte[] and return the html as a byteArray. 
I based this on this Java code

```
public byte[] createHtml(String xmlPath, String xslPath) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath));
    StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(new File(xslPath));
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
    transformer.transform(xml, new StreamResult(writer));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the irrelevant code from the method, leaving only what exactly answers the question.

```
public byte[] CreateHtml(string xmlRoute, string xlsRoute)
{
    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(xlsRoute);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        xslt.Transform(xmlRoute, writer);

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```